# MS Access database - reshaping a table for process mining

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having some trouble getting data in the correct shape for a process mining task. I have received an MS access 2010 database containing some tables a bit like this:

> ```
> caseID    event1_date    event2_date    event3_date
> 1         2013-03-09     2013-04-09     2013-05-09
> 2         2013-03-15     2013-03-21     2013-05-02
> 3         2013-04-01     2013-04-15     2013-06-20
> ```

I want to reshape it to look like this:

> ```
> eventID    caseID    event    date
> 1          1         event1   2013-03-09
> 2          2         event1   2013-03-15
> 3          2         event2   2013-03-21
> 4          3         event1   2013-04-01
> 5          1         event2   2013-04-09
> 6          3         event2   2013-04-15
> 7          2         event3   2013-05-02
> 8          1         event3   2013-05-09
> 9          3         event3   2013-06-20
> ```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the existing table is named [tblCases].

Create the following query in Access and save it as [qryUnpivotEvents]

```sql
    SELECT tblCases.caseID, "event1" AS event, tblCases.event1_date AS eventDate
    FROM tblCases
UNION ALL
    SELECT tblCases.caseID, "event2" AS event, tblCases.event2_date AS eventDate
    FROM tblCases
UNION ALL
    SELECT tblCases.caseID, "event3" AS event, tblCases.event3_date AS eventDate
    FROM tblCases
```

Using the Access UI, create your new table named [tblEvents] with the following fields:

```
  [eventID]: AutoNumber, Primary Key
   [caseID]: Number, Long Integer
    [event]: Text(10)
[eventDate]: Date/Time
```

Run the following Append query to copy the data into the new table

```sql
INSERT INTO tblEvents (caseID, event, eventDate)
SELECT caseID, event, eventDate
FROM qryUnpivotEvents
```

Once this is completed you can delete the [qryUnpivotEvents] query since it will no longer be used.